# didSelectItemAtIndexPath not always called on first element in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a collection view and the tap on the first element of my **UICollectionView** seems to be hit and miss (mostly misses) i.e the callback **didSelectItemAtIndexPath** does not get called.

This **only affects my first element** and I have no problems selecting any other cells from my `UICollectionView`? My `UICollectionView` makes use of **CustomCells**.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: show your view hierarchy!!!! Can you scroll the collection view from the first cell without any issue ?

Comment: Does your first cell contain any views that might be "eating" your touches, like UIButtons, UIViews with gesture recognizers, or UIViews with userInteractionEnabled = YES?

Comment: Thanks guys, I figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I wasn't resizing my UICollectionView header which was thus siting above the first cell and absorbing the touches.